# Angular 4 LazyLoad child routes fails when child has same path

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an app that shows a list of contacts with the ability to select a single contact and view it's details.  A contact detail page has several tabs for sub-information about a contact (profile, touch-points, and contact info).  Here are the pertinent URLs:

**To see a list of contact:**

- http://localhost:4200/contact/list

**To see all touch points for a given contact**

- http://localhost:4200/contact/84/touch-points/list

Here's the routing data that constructs the route for contact list as well as lazy load routes for contact details:

```
    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(
    [
        {
            path: 'list',
            component: PageContactListComponent
        },
        //... other routes here...
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: PageContactDetailComponent,
            children:
            [
                //... other routes here...
                //LAZY LOADED:
                { path: 'touch-points',     loadChildren: './detail/components/touch-points/touch-points.module#TouchPointModule' }             ]
        }
    ]);
```

Here's the routing data for touch-points module.

```
    export const routing:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(
    [   
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'list'
        },
        {
            path: 'list',
            component: TouchPointListComponent
        }
    ]);
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/contact/list`, Angular tries to load the component associated with `http://localhost:4200/contact/84/touch-points/list`.  It seems to do this because 'list' is also defined in a lazy-loaded module.  If I change 'list' to 'history' in routing data for touch-points module, then `http://localhost:4200/contact/list` loads the appropriate component.

Angular 4 router should be able to differentiate between these routes: (`http://localhost:4200/contact/list`, `http://localhost:4200/contact/84/touch-points/list`) and load the appropriate component.

What changes do I need to make to my route definitions to facilitate using 'list' in multiple routes within the same functional area (ie contacts)?

**### --- UPDATE 08/01/2017 ---**

I created the following plunker that demonstrates this issue:

- [plunker demonstrating route getting squashed](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sl4BAzAh7wmSB16m3WPE?p=preview)

Clicking on 'Contact List' link in plunker loads a list of touch-points instead of loading a list of contacts.  Touch Points is a lazy-loaded module inside Contact domain.

What's supposed to happen is to navigate to a list of contacts.  Clicking on a contact should take you to contact detail page allowing you to click on touch-point link to see a list of touch points for the selected contact.

Contact module's list route (`/contact/list`) uses 'list' for it's route.  The touchpoint list route needs to be `/contact/:id/touch-points/list`.  Because `list` is used in both routes, the last route defined overrides the first route and subsequently the component for touchpoint list gets loaded when navigating to `/contact/list` route.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say this: "When I navigate to http://localhost:4200/contact/list" what do you mean exactly? Are you typing this into the address bar? Or using a RouterLink or .navigate()?

Comment: navigating to these different URLs in browser.

Comment: So, typing them into the address bar? Then this sounds like a bug. You can check here and see if it has already been reported: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: Did you bring this up to the team in the Angular repo? Get any traction there?

Comment: I've not had a chance to submit a bug report to Angular Repo yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're gonna smack your forehead when you see what it was.

You were importing the TouchPoint module in your contact.module.ts (line 4 and line 15).  This is what was stomping over your 'list' path.

Remove those, and it works fine.

Comment: OUUCH.  Wow, thank you.  I was assuming I had to import the child module so the parent would know about it.  I learned something new today.  Thank you very much.  Easiest bounty earned all year.